# Why breakpoint breaks at else block in 'if else' condition

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to figure out, why, if I put breakpoints on `if` and on `else` line, why my `if else {}` condition breaks on `else` if the condition was `true` in `if` block?

I am using realm  but I do not think, that is an issue.

```
//Check if Object already exists in database
if !RealmService.shared.ifPortfolioExists(name: portfolio.name){//Breakpoint on this line which is true

     //Create portfolio
     RealmService.shared.create(portfolio)
     //Assign portfolio to transaction
     transaction.portfolio = portfolio
     //Create transaction
     RealmService.shared.create(transaction)

}else{//Breakpoint on this line

     //Assign portfolio to transaction       
     transaction.portfolio = portfolio
     //Create transaction
     RealmService.shared.create(transaction)

}
```

Am I working out of my mind or am I just stupid? Can please someone explain me this.

Comment: I don't think this really qualifies as an answer, but I can tell you from experience that Xcode breakpoints have all kinds of strange behavior if you put them on lines without statements (e.g. the line here, a line with just a brace, a blank line, etc.) I'd recommend getting into the habit of only putting breakpoints on lines with statements (lines that actually do something, like calling a function, assigning a value to a variable, etc.)

Comment: Another thought that might clarify this: the line with `else` in it is *not* inside the `else` case, even though it begins that case.

Answer (score 0):

> The compiler reads them to see if it should proceed into the following block of code. A breakpoint inside of the `if` will trigger when true and `else` when false

Do this to better understand where your breakpoints take effect:

```
if x != y {
    print("if breakpoint")//set breakpoint here
} else {
    print("else breakpoint")//set breakpoint here
    // you should see that the breakpoint doesn't fire here
}
```